# How to prove $\mathcal F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is a contraction?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, contraction-operator

I'm trying to prove that the map $\mathcal F$ below is well-defined and is a contraction. I'm able to complete the first part, but stuck at the second one.

Could you please leave me some hints to finish the second one? Thank you so much!

> Let $\rho >0$ and $f,g \in \mathbb R^n$ in which $\mathbb R^n$ is endowed with the inner product $$\forall x,y \in \mathbb R^n:\langle x, y \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$$
>
> Assume that $\textbf{M}$ is a squared matrix satisfying there is $\alpha >0$ such that $$\forall x \in \mathbb R^n: \langle x, \textbf{M}x \rangle \ge \alpha \|x\|^2$$
>
> We denote $x \ge y$ if $x_i \ge y_i$ for all $i = \overline{1,n}$. We denote by $\mathcal F (x)$ the solution $y \ge f$ (if exists) of $$\forall v \ge f: \langle y-x + \rho(\textbf{M}x -g), v-y \rangle \ge 0$$
>
> Prove that $\mathcal F$ is well defined and is a contraction.

---

**My attempt:**

Let $S := \{v \in \mathbb R^n \mid v \ge f\}$. It follows that $S$ is closed and convex.

The condition $$\forall v \ge f: \langle y-x + \rho(\textbf{M}x -g), v-y \rangle \ge 0$$ is then equivalent to $$\forall v \in S: \left  \langle \big(x - \rho(\textbf{M}x -g)\big) - y, v-y  \right\rangle \le 0$$

It follows that $y$ is the orthogonal projection of $x - \rho(\textbf{M}x -g)$ on the set $S$. Hence $\mathcal F:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is well defined.

Comment: Is $\|x\|$ the Euclidean norm?

Comment: Yes, it is the norm induced from the inner product :) @TheSimpliFire

Comment: I may misunderstand something, but if I take $f=g=0$, $\rho=1$ and $M=\alpha I$ for large $\alpha$, then the projection of $(1-\alpha)x$ onto the positive cone is not a contraction, since $(1-\alpha)$ amplifies the length of $x$ way too much.

Comment: Thank you so much @A.Γ.! I'm going to write an email to my professor to tell her about this problem. I will inform you as soon as I get her reply.

Comment: Hi @A.Γ., my professor replied that there is an error in the exercise. In fact, it is *find $\rho > 0$ such that $\mathcal F$ is a contraction*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My professor replied that there is an error in the exercise. In fact, it is find $ρ>0$ such that $\mathcal F$ is a contraction.

I post it as an answer to peacefully close this question.